# Replacing all characters in a string at once in a for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, methods, char

I am learning Java and I have the following method that changes a specific letter in a string:

```
replaceLetter("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");

        public static void replaceLetter(String string){
        string = string.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'o'){
//              System.out.println("inside if " + i);
//              System.out.println("Char at " + string.charAt(i));
                System.out.println(string.replace(string.charAt(i), '*'));
                break;
            }
//            System.out.println("Outside if " + i);
        }
    }
```

What I don't understand is why is changing all the letters "o" at once, and not one by one as I thought it was supposed to do. The loop loops 12 times outside the "if statement", then goes inside the statement and changes all the characters the matches the case "o". Since the condition is "string.charAt(i)", shouldn't it change one by one? Shouldn't it change the first character that matches the case then break out of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [javadoc for `replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), it (emphasis mine):

> Replaces **each** substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

It sounds like you're looking for [`replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to replace a single occurrence of a character at a time.

Comment: OP don't use the function you linked or doc quoted

Answer (score 2):

Because that is what String#replace(char, char) does.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing **all** occurrences of
> oldChar in this string with newChar.

If you want to only replace one character at a time, use [String#replaceFirst(char, char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

You can use setCharAt of the StringBuilder, so your snippet will look like:

```
public static String replaceLetter(String string){

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string.toLowerCase());
    for (int i = 0; i < stringBuilder.length(); i++){
        if (stringBuilder.charAt(i) == 'o'){
            stringBuilder.setCharAt(i, '*');
            break;
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Also, String are immutable in Java. You need to create a new string with the character replaced.

Answer (score 0):

`string.replace(char a, char b)` replaces all the occurrences of `char a` in `string` with `char b`. So you may want to use `string.replaceFirst` instead.